# Table issue between Firefox and Chrome browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I encounter an issue between **Firefox** and **Chrome** browsers, with the header of a site which I work on. This header consists by a `table` with one row and five columns and also five images in every cell. When I browse it using Firefox everything is fine but in Chrome, looks awful!!!

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Simonetos/qj55x426/) is a jsfiddle example... First open it with Firefox then with Chrome and you'll see what I mean.

HTML code example:

```
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G77gAVEAJp0/V4DD8-FTVDI/AAAAAAAAAIc/R-2o3WPNCIMCerkHw3WtgAjggU4aDpmPQCCo/h423/1.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></td>
            <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nz4se8JDQbI/V4DD80YrdkI/AAAAAAAAAIg/GlqXDawh4cQLsq9M7hs3o425WYnk_Y_pwCCo/h423/2.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></td>
            <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ME4eiHfFCX0/V4DD83Ch1SI/AAAAAAAAAIk/n8jzIfpt08EckyGkLGovVZ_daASbnZphwCCo/h423/3.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></td>
            <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tjmxMwltAQk/V4DD9KIY_xI/AAAAAAAAAIo/Tgyg1Jn08NYyyDF6wO-3g5pJ99su1yKUgCCo/h423/4.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></td>
            <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1bidacvkedc/V4DD9G7jsYI/AAAAAAAAAIs/D4Xnt38y6UgyQ-BwnfHflXUtQ4AraoFegCCo/h423/5.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="menu">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

CSS code example:

```
 body {
 background-color:rgb(255,0,0); 
 }

 img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 0;
 }

.menu {
 background-color:rgb(239,239,239);
 }
```

Any kind of help would be welcome!!!

Comment: Your images are sliced and diced wrong

Comment: Paste the code into the question, please.

Comment: @CarolMcKay: Why do you think they are???

Comment: @Juhana: I have added a jsfiddle example my friend!!!

Comment: Partial 2: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nz4se8JDQbI/V4DD80YrdkI/AAAAAAAAAIg/GlqXDawh4cQLsq9M7hs3o425WYnk_Y_pwCCo/h423/2.png

Comment: @CarolMcKay: No, it's OK. The number it is just for the example... :)

Comment: Yes, but that's not enough. The code must be in the question too.

Comment: @Juhana: OK I'll add a code example too...

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<body>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G77gAVEAJp0/V4DD8-FTVDI/AAAAAAAAAIc/R-2o3WPNCIMCerkHw3WtgAjggU4aDpmPQCCo/h423/1.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></li>
            <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nz4se8JDQbI/V4DD80YrdkI/AAAAAAAAAIg/GlqXDawh4cQLsq9M7hs3o425WYnk_Y_pwCCo/h423/2.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></li>
            <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ME4eiHfFCX0/V4DD83Ch1SI/AAAAAAAAAIk/n8jzIfpt08EckyGkLGovVZ_daASbnZphwCCo/h423/3.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></li>
            <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tjmxMwltAQk/V4DD9KIY_xI/AAAAAAAAAIo/Tgyg1Jn08NYyyDF6wO-3g5pJ99su1yKUgCCo/h423/4.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></li>
            <li><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1bidacvkedc/V4DD9G7jsYI/AAAAAAAAAIs/D4Xnt38y6UgyQ-BwnfHflXUtQ4AraoFegCCo/h423/5.png" alt="" height="" width=""/></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="menu">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
 background-color:rgb(255,0,0); 
 }

 ul {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   display:flex;
 }

 img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 0;
 }

.menu {
 background-color:rgb(239,239,239);
 }
```

LINK

https://jsfiddle.net/5dyqqsv7/

Comment: Did you test it in Firefox? Cause it works for Chrome but In Firefox the 3rd image appears smaller in height!!! Take a look [here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_DVuRDjBYQw/V4DVb53BUgI/AAAAAAAAAI8/GQpzIjlyoxkvAuvixyMRRjPL4Mxu9_GCwCCo/s697/Example.png)

Comment: Yes I did @Simonetos at which point I figured it would come down to the actual website layout sizes and ran away :-P

Comment: I am not sure I get exactly what you said my friend... :(

Comment: @Simonetos I thought that the author would specify the actual li sizes himself in his project later. So I left him to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make it work in Firefox... Can you please give me an example on your fiddle?